# Does adding many views to DB affects performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, view

I want to add many views to DB to simplify work with it. I want to use those views only in Server Management Studio for fast testing of DB, querying history, error logs etc.

I think, that count of standard views (not indexed) doesn't affect DB performance.
Am I right? Can I add for example 100 views with no decrease of DB performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding more views, if in hundreds, **will not affect the performance**. At the end of the day, most of the `schema catalog` is in **memory** anyway and is loaded once.

Answer (score 2):

The number of Views available on the DB won't affect performance - however, the way the Views are written and how they get used - will.

Answer (score 1):

100 views are not many, and having many views shouldn't affect performance.